Edge lighting notification in kotlin
I'm trying to program an app that will use the edge lighting notification as shown in the picture. However, I have no idea what to use to handle that.
I have tried using canvas but that's not what I want since its limited to the app itself.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

How to Create a Transparent, Gradient Border Around the Screen in an Android App
For a solution that completely covers the screen regardless of the state/size of the app, you have several options. Here are two effective methods:
Method 1: Using a Second Activity
This method involves creating a second activity that displays a transparent gradient border.
Pros:

Relatively easy to implement.

Cons:

Could interfere with the UI of the main activity.
Requires a specific theme.

Step-by-Step Implementation

Define a Custom Theme for Full-Screen, Transparent Activity

Create a custom theme in res/values/styles.xml that makes the activity full-screen and transparent.
res/values/styles.xml:
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme -->
    <style name="Theme.FullScreenActivitySimulation" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Custom theme for transparent activity -->
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>


Create the Gradient Stroke Drawable

Define a drawable resource for the gradient border effect.
res/drawable/gradient_stroke.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Background color to make the center transparent -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top Edge -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerY="0.03"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="#0000FF"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom Edge -->
    <item android:bottom="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerY="0.97"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:endColor="#0000FF"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Left Edge -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerX="0.03"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="#0000FF"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Right Edge -->
    <item android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerX="0.97"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:endColor="#0000FF"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:angle="0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>


Create the Layout for the Edge Lighting Activity

Create a layout file for the EdgeLightingActivity that uses the gradient stroke drawable as its background.
res/layout/activity_edge_lighting.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/edge_lighting_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke" />
</RelativeLayout>


Implement the Edge Lighting Activity

Implement the EdgeLightingActivity to display the gradient stroke and automatically close after a few seconds.
EdgeLightingActivity.kt:
package com.example.fullscreenactivitysimulation

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat

class EdgeLightingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = "EdgeLightingActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called")

        // Make the activity full-screen using WindowInsetsController
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edge_lighting)

        // Set a timer to close the activity after a few seconds
        val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        handler.postDelayed({
            finish()
        }, 3000) // Show the edge lighting for 3 seconds
    }
}


Launch the Edge Lighting Activity from MainActivity

Add a Floating Action Button (FAB) in MainActivity to launch the EdgeLightingActivity.
MainActivity.kt:
package com.example.fullscreenactivitysimulation

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material3.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.fullscreenactivitysimulation.ui.theme.FullScreenActivitySimulationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            FullScreenActivitySimulationTheme {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = {
                                val intent = Intent(this, EdgeLightingActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                            }
                        ) {
                            Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "Localized description")
                        }
                    }
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    FullScreenActivitySimulationTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}


Declare the Custom Theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Ensure the custom theme is applied to your activity in the manifest file.
AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreenActivitySimulation">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".EdgeLightingActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent" />
        
    </application>
</manifest>

To ensure the gradient border is only viewable for a set amount of time after a button click in Method 2, you can programmatically add the border view, display it for a specified duration, and then remove it.
Here's how to modify the implementation to achieve this:
Method 2: Drawing Directly to the Main Activity
You can also draw directly to the screen by setting the appropriate theme in the main activity, which controls the total area the app will draw.
Pros:

Does not interfere with the main activity's UI.

Cons:

Requires proper theme configuration for edge-to-edge control.

Step-by-Step Implementation

Ensure the Custom Theme is Defined

Ensure you have the custom theme defined as shown in Method 1.

Update the Main Activity Layout

Modify your main activity layout to include a FrameLayout that overlays the gradient border drawable on top of your main content.
<!-- res/layout/activity_main.xml -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Main content goes here -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Your main content here -->
        <!-- Example: -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, World!"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Gradient border overlay, initially invisible -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/gradient_border_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_stroke"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- FloatingActionButton to trigger the border display
    <com.google.android.material3.FloatingActionButton -->
    <!-- FloatingActionButton to trigger the border display -->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</FrameLayout>


MainActivity Implementation

Add functionality to display the gradient border for a set amount of time after a button click.
// MainActivity.kt
package com.example.fullscreenactivitysimulation

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var gradientBorderView: View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        gradientBorderView = findViewById(R.id.gradient_border_view)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            showGradientBorderForLimitedTime(3000) // Show for 3 seconds
        }
    }

    private fun showGradientBorderForLimitedTime(duration: Long) {
        gradientBorderView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            gradientBorderView.visibility = View.GONE
        }, duration)
    }
}


Declare the Custom Theme in AndroidManifest.xml

Ensure the custom theme is applied to your activity in the manifest file.
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>

Summary
Method 1: Using a Second Activity

Create a second activity with a custom theme to display a gradient border.

Method 2: Drawing Directly to the Main Activity

Directly draw the gradient border in the main activity using a FrameLayout and proper theme configuration.
Programmatically show the border for a limited time after a button click.

By following these steps, you can create a transparent, gradient border directly on your main activity, achieving a clean and integrated effect without the need for a separate activity. The border will only be viewable for a set amount of time after the button is clicked.
